# Conditionally grep and concatenate lines in CSVs based on keyword

Tags: python, linux, pandas, command-line, subprocess

I have two CSVs that are too large (20M rows each) to load into Pandas in their entirety and then filter for the subset that I actually need. (The final output needs to be a Pandas dataframe.) I'm using `subprocess` to grep all the lines that match the string that occurs in all the lines I need, and then I use `BytesIO` to read the output.

```
from io import BytesIO
import subprocess as sub
import pandas as pd

output = sub.check_output(f'grep -i "{string}" /path/for/csv/file.csv', shell=True)

df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(output))
```

I do this for both files, then concatenate them with Pandas. The problem is that in some cases, the string appears only in one of the two files. Currently I'm using this if statement to keep the script from throwing an error:

```
output = sub.check_output(f'grep -i "{string}" /path/for/csv/file.csv | wc -l', shell=True)

if output > 0:
     ...
```

What I'm trying to wrap my mind around is how to conditionally concatenate the results together so that both outputs are saved to variables if the string appears anywhere in the csvs and then concatenated together only if the string appears in both CSVs.

At the moment the most succinct way I can think to do this is to check both CSVs and save the output to two different variables

```
output_1 = sub.check_output(f'grep -i "{string}" /path/for/csv/file1.csv | wc -l', shell=True)
output_2 = sub.check_output(f'grep -i "{string}" /path/for/csv/file2.csv | wc -l', shell=True)
```

and then write a series of conditional statements:

```
if (output_1 > 0) & (output_2 > 0):

    output = sub.check_output(f'grep -i "{string}" /path/for/csv/file.csv1', shell=True)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(output))

    output = sub.check_output(f'grep -i "{string}" /path/for/csv/file.csv2', shell=True)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(output))

    df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)

elif (output_1 > 0) & (output_2 < 1):

    output = sub.check_output(f'grep -i "{string}" /path/for/csv/file.csv1', shell=True)
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(output))

elif (output_1 < 1) & (output_2 > 0):

    output = sub.check_output(f'grep -i "{string}" /path/for/csv/file.csv2', shell=True)
    df = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(output))

else:

    print(f'{string} does not appear in the files.)
```

This seems unnecessarily clunky & isn't robust to needing to do the same type of thing with three or more CSVs. Is there a way to do this in a way that more efficient/succinct for two CSVs, or that additionally could handle 3+ CSVs as easily as 2?

Edit:

I've also tried the following (a suggestion from @Shawn), but currently it's performing 3x slower than grep (8.7s vs 2.6s):

```
%%time
file_path = '/path/for/csv/file.csv'

with open(file_path) as csvfile:
    filtered = list(filter(lambda row: ('nonadmd' in row), csvfile))
```

Then I'm doing the following to get it into dataframe format:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(filtered)
df.columns = ['all_data']
df = pd.DataFrame(df.all_data.apply(lambda x: x.split(',')).tolist(), index=df.index)
```

Sample data:

```
import random
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': random.choices(['A', 'B', 'C'], k=4*10**6),
    'col2': random.sample(range(0, 100), k=4*10**6)
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': random.choices(['A', 'B', 'C'], k=4*10**6),
    'col2': random.sample(range(0, 100), k=4*10**6)
})
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're dragging external programs like grep into something that can be done very easily natively in python.

Comment: @Shawnn, the files are too large, so some processing is done in the shell, before reading into pandas. The OP explained at the start of the question

Comment: Kindly create sample data that can be reproduced. I could try something on my end and see if a solution is possible

Comment: @sammywemmy I mean, straight up python. Open the file, read it line by line looking for a substring. None of this pandas stuff.

Comment: @Shawn Are you suggesting running 40M rows through a for loop with Python's `csv`, or is there a better way to do that?

Comment: @KristianCanler Yes. Though from the looks of it even the csv library might be overkill.

Comment: @Shawn What do you suggest running in the for loop to output a Pandas dataframe or something `pd.read_csv()` can read?

Comment: Forget `pd.read_csv()` exists. You can create a dataframe from a python list, and/or add a row at a time to one.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `pd.DataFrame()`.

Comment: So far this is performing about 3x slower than grep (8.7s vs. 2.6s), using a lambda function and filter rather than a loop.

Comment: So, what string are you searching for. You could try Shawn's suggestion ... Read the file and maybe use readlines

Comment: I'm searching for any one of them, A, B, or C. I tried Shawn 's suggestion (but with filter lambda rather than loop); that's what performed 3x slower. I'm trying readlines now

Comment: Maybe concatenate files before: `cat *.csv | grep -i ...`

Comment: Is there any header in the CSV? It seems they are ignored in this computation (despite headers can contain the searched string). Note that the sample-data code does not works (both the `random.choices` and the `random.sample` calls have issues)

Comment: @Corralien That was the right answer! (Or it works at least without sacrificing speed.) Feel free to write up as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way is to `cat` all csv before using `grep`:

```sh
$ cat *.csv | grep -i ...
```